# "Target container is not a DOM element" before building

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep getting this error with React:

```
_registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

I'm using "create-react-app" with Yarn. There's three main files of code.

Here's the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="hw"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And index.js:

```
import './index.css'

import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'

import Hello from './Hello'

render(<Hello/>, document.querySelector('#hw'))
```

And Hello.js

```
import './helloworld.css'
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Hello extends Component {
  render() {
    return
      <div className="HelloWorld-hello HelloWorld-flex">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
  }
}

export default Hello
```

I've tried everything I can think of. All files are in the same "src" directory. This all started when I was trying to render two components within index.js using this:

```
render(
  <div>
    <Hello/>
    <World/>
  </div>,
document.querySelector('#hw'))
```

Comment: What if you use `document.getElementById('hw')` instead of querySelector?

Comment: I've tried that too. Here's a pic of the the error message.

https://ibb.co/d6Xdzv

Comment: You have to use React.render(<Hello/>, document.getElementById('hw')).
Take a look here http://jsbin.com/gogibukeqi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: When I do React.render I get this error

    `TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_react___default.a.render is not a function`

In my image above I mistakenly put "getDocumentById" instead of "getElementById". Either way its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issues, although I don't understand why one is happening. Apparantely, it's only working when I use `root` as the name of the div in index.html.

```
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

And index.js

```
import './index.css'

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import Hello from './Hello'
import World from './World'

ReactDOM.render(<div><Hello/><World/></div>, 
document.getElementById('root'))
```

In the  `Hello.js` file, I placed the div outside of the line with `return`. Once I moved the div to start on that line.

```
import './helloworld.css'
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Hello extends Component {
  render() {
    return  <div className="HelloWorld-hello HelloWorld-flex">
              <h1>Hello</h1>
            </div>
    }
  }

export default Hello
```

I think I understand why I would need to put the `<div>` on the same line as the `return`, but I'm completely clueless about why only the word `root` works for the div id. I've tried all kinds of other words and get the same error.

Ultimately I was trying to have two separate child components (Hello.js and World.js) nested under a parent component (index.js).